# How to prevent overlap of my context menu with the system menu in the Windows notification area?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, system-tray

I've seen a lot of "unofficial" workarounds to bypass this visual bug, but none of them seem to work correctly for me. Let me explain.

Say, I display my own system tray icon in the Windows notification area (by the clock.)

[image]

My program also supports displaying a context menu when a user right-clicks my tray icon. I implement it by trapping the `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` notification from the message handler specified in the `uCallbackMessage` parameter of the `NOTIFYICONDATA`. I then processing it as such:

```
//Show menu (ask to return results here)
int nRes = TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_RIGHTALIGN | TPM_TOPALIGN |
    TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_VERPOSANIMATION | TPM_HORNEGANIMATION | TPM_RETURNCMD,
    pnt.x, pnt.y, 0, this->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL);
```

Unfortunately the code above, all by itself, does not allow the menu to be dismissed after a left-click somewhere outside of it.

To resolve this, the solution I found was this:

```
//Need this to bypass a glitch in Windows to remove popup menu from
//System Tray after mouse click outside of it
::SetForegroundWindow(this->GetSafeHwnd());

//Show menu (ask to return results here)
int nRes = TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_RIGHTALIGN | TPM_TOPALIGN |
    TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_VERPOSANIMATION | TPM_HORNEGANIMATION | TPM_RETURNCMD,
    pnt.x, pnt.y, 0, this->GetSafeHwnd(), NULL);

PostMessage(WM_NULL, 0, 0);
```

But the "fix" above introduces an occasional additional bug.

For instance, here's a screenshot from Windows 8. Sometimes, I think it depends on what window had focus prior to this, when I right-click on my tray icon my context menu is displayed on top of the Windows default context menu, that looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this visual bug of overlapping context menus?

Comment: From the documentation: "If the current window is a child window, you must set the (top-level) parent window as the foreground window.". Did you do that?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: What documentation are you referring to?

Comment: The documentation of `TrackPopupMenu` is available [online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Don't add a cancel option. The way to cancel a menu is to click elsewhere.

Comment: Another cool way to cancel is to hit Escape.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, I agree. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The code in the question is fine. It's how we all do it. There must be something else.

Comment: On a separate note, instead of using `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` I would suggest using `WM_RBUTTONUP` and `WM_CONTEXTMENU` instead (use `NIM_SETVERSION` to tell Windows which one to send). Also, consider also handling `NIN_KEYSELECT` and `NIN_SELECT` for users who use the keyboard to activate the tray icon menu instead of using the mouse.